# Fixed-effects model including variable that is constant for a given unit

Tags: panel-data, fixed-effects-model

I know I cannot use time-invariant variables in fixed effects panel models. Is it possible however to use a variable which is time-invariant only for some of the units in a dataset?

For example, can I use variable X here?

unit time Z

A    1    10

A    2    10

A    3    10

B    1    4

B    2    6

B    3    7

C    1    55

C    2    80

C    3    100

...

Comment: What is variable X?

Comment: If you meant Z (rather than X): yes, this is possible.